# Access WSL2 distro's VPN network from Windows 11 host

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am running an debian 11 in WSL2, and I am connecting to a VPN network using openvpn. Within the distro (from CLI) I can reach the desired remote hosts, but I cannot reach them from Windows.

Here is my configuration:

- I created with VMSwitch a bridge, so i have the same subnet as my host.
- openvpn is set on my wsl2

I tried to add route who is pointing my wsl2 network card tun0 (who is my vpn) get it work but with not success

I also tried to put openvpn on my host but i can't access to the remote hosts in my wsl2...

What should I do in order to reach the remote hosts within the VPN from Windows?